# checking out specific directory out of a GIT repo

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to check out a specific folder (as per below, e.g.: 10.0-RC-3) from a GIT repo in jenkins pipeline.

I have below structure in GIT repo : https://gitlab.xxx.org/Titan/Testing/Test-project/

10.0-RC-1

10.0-RC-2

10.0-RC-3

I tried with below code, but that didn't work

```
stage(checkout specific folder){
scm:[
userRemoteConfigs:[
[
credintialsId: 'MySecretId',
url: 'https://gitlab.xxx.org/Titan/Testing/Test-project.git'
name: env.gitlabTargetNamespace
]
]
]
sh "git archive --remote='https://gitlab.xxx.org/Titan/Testing/Test-project/' 'master' '10.0-RC-3'
}
```

i getting error as "fatal:operation not supported by protocol".

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use an SSH URL instead for git archive to work with GitLab repositories. See [this thread as an illustration](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/does-gitlab-support-git-archive-remote/23521/2?u=vonc).

> ```
> git archive --remote git@gitlab.com:path/to/project.git -o test.zip HEAD
> ```
>
> The format for your SSH connection should be as follows:
>
> ```
> git@<hostname>:path/to/project.git
> ```

But you could also consider an [API call](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#get-file-archive)

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
     "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/archive?sha=<commit_sha>&path=<path>"
```